# pandas filter by a range of datetime after grouby

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter

I'd like to calculate the change in each student's score for each subject over time, based on a period of time.

For example:

Here is the original table

| Datetime | Student | Subject | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | Math | 70 |
| 2021-03-01 | A | Physics I | 80 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | Physics I | 80 |
| 2021-02-15 | A | Math | 90 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | Physics I | 95 |
| 2021-02-11 | A | Physics I | 90 |
| 2021-05-15 | A | Physics I | 80 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | Math | 80 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | Math | 100 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Here is a table sorted by Student, then by Subject.

| Datetime | Student | Subject | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | Math | 70 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | Math | 100 |
| 2021-02-15 | A | Math | 90 |
| 2021-02-01 | A | Physics I | 80 |
| 2021-02-11 | A | Physics I | 90 |
| 2021-03-01 | A | Physics I | 80 |
| 2021-05-15 | A | Physics I | 80 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | Math | 80 |
| 2021-02-01 | B | Physics I | 95 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Assume here is a sequence of time period [2021-01-01 ~ 2021-02-10, 2021-02-14 ~ 2021-02-17]

For Student A, Subject Math, time period "2020-01-01 ~ 2021-02-10", the change of score would be

| Datetime | Student | Subject | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | Math | NaN |
| 2021-02-01 | A | Math | 30 |

For Student A, Subject Physics I, time period "2020-01-01 ~ 2021-02-10", the change of score would be

| Datetime | Student | Subject | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | A | Physics I | NaN |

For Student A, Subject Math, time period "2020-02-14 ~ 2021-02-17", the change of score would be

| Datetime | Student | Subject | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-15 | A | Math | NaN |

My first attempt was so slow that I used so many for-loops to calculate as below

```
period_time = [(pd.to_datetime(2021-01-01), pd.to_datetime(2021-02-10))]

students = df['Student'].unique()
for student in students:
    student_table = df.loc[df['Student'] == student]

    subjects = student_table['Subject'].unique()
    for subject in subjects:
        subject_table = student_table.loc[student_table['Subject'] == subject]
        
        for time in period_time:
            start = time[0]
            end   = time[1]
            res_table = subject_table.loc[ (start <= subject_table['Datetime']) & 
                                           (subject_table['Datetime'] <= end)]
            diff = res_table['Score'].diff()
```

Then I try to use build-in function 'groupby' to classify the 'Student' and 'Subject' as below

```
df.groupby(['Student', 'Subject'], group_keys = False)
```

However,I got no idea how should I classify the datetime by given a certain period time. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) for filter before [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and assign only filtered rows:

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

df = df.sort_values(['Student','Subject'])

period_time = [(pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01'), pd.to_datetime('2021-02-10')),
               (pd.to_datetime('2021-02-14'), pd.to_datetime('2021-02-17'))]

for (start, end) in period_time:
    m = df['Datetime'].between(start, end)
    df.loc[m, 'Score'] = df[m].groupby(['Student', 'Subject'])['Score'].diff()

print (df)
    Datetime Student    Subject  Score
0 2021-01-01       A       Math    NaN
3 2021-02-15       A       Math    NaN
8 2021-02-01       A       Math   30.0
1 2021-03-01       A  Physics I   80.0
2 2021-02-01       A  Physics I    NaN
5 2021-02-11       A  Physics I   90.0
6 2021-05-15       A  Physics I   80.0
7 2021-02-01       B       Math    NaN
4 2021-02-01       B  Physics I    NaN
```

If need column only with count new values:

```
for (start, end) in period_time:
    m = df['Datetime'].between(start, end)
    df.loc[m, 'Score_new'] = df[m].groupby(['Student', 'Subject'])['Score'].diff()

print (df)
    Datetime Student    Subject  Score  Score_new
0 2021-01-01       A       Math     70        NaN
3 2021-02-15       A       Math     90        NaN
8 2021-02-01       A       Math    100       30.0
1 2021-03-01       A  Physics I     80        NaN
2 2021-02-01       A  Physics I     80        NaN
5 2021-02-11       A  Physics I     90        NaN
6 2021-05-15       A  Physics I     80        NaN
7 2021-02-01       B       Math     80        NaN
4 2021-02-01       B  Physics I     95        NaN
```